# How to set a dismiss listener in a dialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `listView`, and when a user exits the dialog and decides not to continue I want to uncheck that item. The problem is- I am having trouble knowing if the user dismisses the dialog or not. This is the best ive been able to come up with

```
// inside a DialogFragment
@Override
public void dismiss() {
    Log.d("dismiss", "Dismissed");
    if (logEntries.customLocation == false) {
        logEntries.drawer.customLocationNotSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to set a listener to track a dialog dismissal?

Comment: What's wrong with that approach you just found?

Comment: DialogFragments don't allow you to set you're own onDismissListener so that is the best approach. You can ofcourse create your own extension of a DialogFragment with its callbacks but that is probably overkill

Comment: Also just a little code cleanup :P `logEntries.drawer.customLocationNotSelected(!logEntries.customLocation);` 

Can be used to replace the if statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean flag like

```
boolean isSavedCheck = false;
```

On setPositiveButton() method, if the selected items are saved, set isSavedCheck = true;

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        isSavedCheck = true;
     });
```

If the setNegativeButton() is called and isSavedCheck = false; then cancel all check items.

```
.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        if(!isSavedCheck){
           // cancel all check boxes
        }
     });
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I check if someone exits through hitting the back button or clicking off screen?